# How to integrate the following elliptic curve period

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve given by 
$$ y^2=x^3-fx^2+\frac{1}{b}x $$ and let one the cycles of the torus be $A$. Then the period integral is
\begin{equation}a= \oint_A \lambda 
\end{equation}
and this is given by the solution of $$ \frac{d \lambda}{df}=\frac{dx}{y}.$$ So, how exactly do we find $a$?

I am trying to directly put $y = \sqrt{x^3-fx^2+\frac{1}{b}x}$ in the differential equation but I do not get somewhere. I am sure there is some kind of identity helping with this. It seems a standard thing to do in the theory of elliptic curves but nowhere is done explicitly.

Comment: I don't get it. What is $\lambda$ ? and $A$ is the boundary of [the period parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers) ? In that case you have to find $\omega_1,\omega_2$ first

Comment: $\lambda$ is the solution of the differential equation given above. Then, its integration over the cycle$A$ gives $a$. E.g. it could be that $\lambda = \# \frac{x-u}{y}dx$.

Comment: If $A$ is the boundary of $[0,1]\omega_1+[0,1]\omega_2$ then the you have to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#The_constants_e1.2C_e2_and_e3 for computing $\omega_1,\omega_2$. And what do you want to compute with $a$ ? And your equation $d\lambda/df = dx/dy$ doesn't mean anything to me

Comment: Yes, I need help performing the integration  $$ \oint \frac{dx}{ \sqrt{x^3-fx^2+(1/b)x} } $$

Comment: Since it is a contour integral, you have to say what is the contour (for example $C = \partial P$ where $P = \{z =a_1 a\omega_1+a_2 \omega_2, a_1 \in (0,1),a_2\in (0,1)\}$ and $\omega_1,\omega_2$ as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#The_constants_e1.2C_e2_and_e3 )